# <Spring MVC> Second form on same page causing a lot of errors

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc

A short while ago it was decided that our 'support' tool needed some reforming. This included design and technically. One of these things was making several selections, which were present on any form in the tool, session-scoped.

For this purpose it was decided that we extend our menu-bar with a second form. The form right now is causing a lot of trouble. Namely:

- Some pages don't load at all, and instead give a ***net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING*** error.
- If a page works and I submit the form, the following error occurs: ***Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute***

Whenever I debug the controller-class, it steps through the code and recognises the bound fields, and assigns them to the linked command-class. Whenever I submit the original form (Not the one from the menu-bar) no errors occur.

This is my form (As it stands now, with testing and all that):

```
<form:form method="post" action="userbar">
    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="error"/> 
    <span id="headerImageLeft"><img src="<c:url value="/static/images/temp_tc_logo.png"/>" alt="Ticketcounter"/></span>
    <li id="menuItemProfile"><a href="<c:url value='profile'/>"><spring:message code="button.profile" /></a></li>
    <li id="menuItemChangeList"><a href="<c:url value='changeList'/>"><spring:message code="button.change-list" /></a></li></a>
    <li id="menuItemLogOff"><a href="<c:url value='logout'/>"><spring:message code="button.logout" /></a></li></a>
    <li id="menuItemUsername">
        <spring:message code="label.user"/>:
        <c:out value="${user.username}"/>
    </li>
    <c:if test="${not empty clientsList || not empty casesList}">
        <li id="menuItemClientBrowser">
            Show Archive <form:checkbox path="showArchive" id="showArchive" value="showArchive" onchange="submit();"/>
        </li>
    </c:if>
</form:form>
```

The ***net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING*** is caused by the  part. Whenever I remove that, every page loads normally. Even trying:

```
<spring:bind path="showArchive">
     <input type="checkbox".../>
</spring:bind>
```

gives the error. Whereas on other .jsp files these tags work a-OK.

The pages are built using a template that picks the menubar.jsp and corresponding page-.jsp files and stitches them together. This way the menu is exactly the same throughout the tool.

I hope someone can help me with this issue, and if I've been vague about some things, or maybe if you possibly want to know more, please ask and I shall answer.

Comment: For starters your action is relative and not absolute and I highly doubt that ever page has a `user bar` sub url it matches. Also multiple forms won't work like this as you have to explicitly name the form object to bind to, the default is `command`. I strongly suggest using a dedicated unique name for the search stuff else it simply will not work.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you for the reply. The forms are each bound to a separate bean, for the **userbar** it's the ***userbar*** bean, and for the main-body forms their corresponding beans. The userbar is omni-present, apart from the login screen, as it serves no purpose there.

A previous method explored was to simply use URL parameters, but due to security issues it was dropped. Even with the HTML5 History API exising; not all our clients use HTML5 supporting-browsers, and 'forcing' them to upgrade so we don't have to worry about it is bad business practise.

Comment: Please read my comment... If you post to a reletive URL your beans are useless, you have to post to the exact controller URL else it won't work. Hence you should use an absolute and not relative URL. You must also give it a unique name because if you have multiple forms your other object will not be there anymore or overwritten by another with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it. The errors seemed to have been an issue regarding the **ModelAndView** my Controller was returning in the *onSubmit()* function.

I changed it so that, instead of returning a ModelAndView with a URL *ánd* a Model, it simply returns a RedirectView. No more errors, except for when I change HTML form-elements to Spring form-elements.